# date validation in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

**is this following a proper date validation fn**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="date" Width="80px" MaxLength="10" runat="server" />
          </td>
        <td>            
          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="date"
            ErrorMessage="date. " ValidationExpression="^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$" Display="Static" Font-Names="Arial"
            Font-Size="11" runat="server">
        enter a valid date formate
          </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this would be a better approach, use what's built-in:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="date" Width="80px" MaxLength="10" runat="server" />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="date" ErrorMessage="* Enter a valid date"
     Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date" />
```

The key settings are `Operator` and `Type`.

Note *if you have to consider multiple cultures and such, this becomes a much more involved question, hopefully that isn't the case.*

Comment: I want to validate date in format YYYY-MM-DD. Where to put my format to compare. 'coz above code is also acceptind DD-MM-YYYY